# Backend and Frontend Developers. What are they?

Tags: web-applications, jdeveloper, programmers-notepad

What do back end developers specifically do? How important are they in the process of developing an app?
What about the frontend developers? What do they specifically do? What do they also do?

Answer (score 0):

### Summary of Frontend verses Backend

While both frontend and backend form the basis of how a website works, they have their fair share of differences in terms of functionality. Despite everything, they are like two sides of the same coin. While the former is everything a user sees and interacts with, the latter is what a user cannot see. Frontend refers to the client-side, whereas backend refers to the server-side of the application. Both are crucial to web development, but their roles, responsibilities and the environments they work in are totally different. Frontend is basically what users see whereas backend is how everything works.
[image]

Read more: Difference Between Frontend and Backend | Difference Between | Frontend vs Backend http://www.differencebetween.net/technology/difference-between-frontend-and-backend/#ixzz5i6t41Hi9